# referencing modules in pom packaging

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, parent-pom

How do I reference a module that is included in a pom.xml?

In the `pom.xml` referenced below how would I include the modules on the this pom so that it can be referenced in other projects as so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
        <module>module3</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: to clarify: you want to use a module of a project as a dependency in another project? Is this project yet another module (that is, they same the same aggreator pom) or is it a completely separated project?

Comment: it is a completely separate project.  everything is published to an artifactory, so the artifactory has com.example:parent:1.0-SNAPSHOT & each module as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is to put your sub-modules in the dependencyManagement section of your parent POM like so:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>module3</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then you can configure each of your sub-modules with whatever dependencies they need, without having to worry about the correct version number.

```xml
<!-- module2's dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>module3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

If you declared all the sub-modules as dependencies of the parent POM, then you'd end up with cyclic dependencies. For example:

```
[parent] -> [module1] -> [parent]
```

Maven doesn't like that.